# The sequence $(a_n)$ is defined by $a_1=1$ , $a_n=a_1a_2a_3..a_{n-1}+1$ for $n≥2$ Find the smallest $M$ such that

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series

The sequence $(a_n)$ is defined by $a_1=1$ , $a_n=a_1a_2a_3..a_{n-1}+1$ for $n≥2$
Find the smallest $M$ such that
$\displaystyle\sum^m_{n=1}\frac{1}{a_n}<M$ for all $m\in{\mathbb{N}}$

Comment: What ideas have you had so far? What have you tried?

Comment: The sequence $(a_n)$ is essentially just Sylvester's sequence (with an additional term added at the beginning).

Comment: I found the sum is equal to $2-\frac{1}{a_{m+1}-1}$